# VLOOKUP stops working after 500 rows

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

In Google Sheets I have a search box that brings up the information for a person when you type in their id. It works perfectly up until ID 512, which is row 374. The formula I use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,'Main Database'!B21:S590,3,True),"")
```

Comment: Note that you didn't make the ranges in the lookup table absolute so as you drag your formula down to `C512`, your lookup table is expected to start at `B530`. May not be the issue but thought to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the material in Main Database is sorted by ascending contents of the first column in it.

(It's safest to select the whole range manually and then sort it.)

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is just numerical it may be a problem of Google Sheets not being able to evaluate the comparison due to the numbers being too big. I had the same issue and solved it by concatenating "id" to the start of every id in both the search value and the lookup table.